# Convergence of an improper integral involving trigonometric functions

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> Determine the convergence of the following improper integral:
> $$\int_{2018}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^3x}{x^{\frac{3}{4}}+x^{\frac{1}{6}}\cos x}\,dx$$

Now I thought about using Dirichlet's criteria, but unfortunately $\frac{1}{x^{\frac{3}{4}}+x^{\frac{1}{6}}\cos x}$ is not monotonically decreasing. No relevant change of variables comes to mind also. Am I on the right track?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are correct that the Dirichlet test is not directly applicable because the denominator is not monotone.  However is is "slightly oscillatory" and the approach below is useful in such situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\sin^3 x = \frac{3}{4} \sin x - \frac{1}{4} \sin 3x$ and it is enough to consider the convergence as $c \to \infty$ of the integral

$$\tag{*}\int_{2018}^c\frac{\sin ax}{x^{3/4} + x^{1/6}\cos x}\, dx = \int_{2018}^c\frac{\sin ax}{x^{3/4} }\, dx - \int_{2018}^c\left[\frac{\sin ax}{x^{3/4} + x^{1/6}\cos x} - \frac{\sin ax}{x^{3/4} }\right]\, dx$$

The first integral on the RHS of (*) converges by the Dirichlet test.  For the second integral we have

$$\left|\frac{\sin ax}{x^{3/4} + x^{1/6}\cos x} - \frac{\sin ax}{x^{3/4} }\right| = \left|\frac{\sin ax\cdot x^{1/6}\cos x}{(x^{3/4} + x^{1/6}\cos x)x^{3/4}} \right| = \frac{|\sin ax|\, |\cos x|}{(x^{3/4} + x^{1/6}\cos x)x^{7/12}}\\ \leqslant \frac{1}{(x^{3/4} + x^{1/6}\cos x)x^{7/12}} = \frac{1}{x^{4/3}+ x^{3/4}\cos x}$$

Consequently, the second integral on the RHS of (*) is absolutely convergent by the comparison test, since by the limit comparison test (with $x^{-4/3}$) we have

$$\int_{2018}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^{4/3}+ x^{3/4}\cos x} < \infty$$

Therefore, the improper  integral on the LHS of (*) is convergent.